# Call intercept in Galaxy S3 with Jelly bean 4.1.1 doesn't work when user has chosen "always"?

Tags: android, call, galaxy, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I successfully catch the broadcast and if the number does meet the requirements I terminate this call request and make another, i.e. to allow for user choice popup, my onReceive is here

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    final String oldNumber = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);          

    final String newNumber = this.getResultData();
    boolean useAmivox = true;

    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

    Log.d(DTAG, "bundle: " + bundle.toString());

    Log.d(DTAG, "Number: " + oldNumber );

    if( oldNumber != null ){
        boolean isGlobal= PhoneNumberUtils.isGlobalPhoneNumber(oldNumber);
        Log.d(DTAG, "isGlobal: " + isGlobal );
        boolean isIntl= PhoneNumberUtils.toaFromString(oldNumber)== PhoneNumberUtils.TOA_International ? true:false;
        Log.d(DTAG, "isIntl: " + isIntl );
        useAmivox = isGlobal && isIntl; 
    }
    if( oldNumber.contains(TAG))
        useAmivox=true;


    if ( !oldNumber.contains(TAG) && useAmivox) {

        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, null, null);
        Intent lIntent = new Intent();
        lIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_CALL);

        lIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + oldNumber + TAG));
        lIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER, oldNumber);
        lIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(lIntent);
   }else{
        if (oldNumber != null)
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, oldNumber.replace(TAG, ""),
                    null);
    }
}
```

The manifest is like this

```
<receiver
        android:name="com.amivox.callintercepttest.OutCallInterceptor"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="10" >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

What happens in Galaxy S3 with jelly bean 4.1.1 is that if the user chooses phone, i.e. not my app always, no calls are made, i.e. my broadcastreceiver always gets to set the result to null.   This code has been working since 2.x something and if user has chosen to set "defaults" to "phone" my broadcastreceiver has not had any negative influences ;)  Jelly bean emulator test also works as it should so, but Galaxy S3 with Jelly bean doesn't!  Is there anyone that has had the same problem and found a solution?